# res.format() doesn't work in Express 4.x

Tags: node.js, express

i am rookie in Node.js and start learning Express.
i tried set content-type as text/plain, and it should respond "hey, i am text"
but actually it respond "hey, i am html", and even with status code: 304, Not Modified.

can anyone help out to explain the reason?

```
router.get('/index1.html', function (req, res, next) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.format({
        'text/plain': function () {
            res.send('hey, i am text');
        },

        'text/html': function () {
            res.send('<p>hey, i am html</p>');
        },

        'application/json': function () {
            res.send({ message: 'hey, i am json' });
        },

        'default': function () {
            // log the request and respond with 406
            res.status(406).send('Not Acceptable');
        }
    });
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Express [document](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.format), `res.format()` means:

> Performs content-negotiation **on the Accept HTTP header on the request object**, when present...select a handler for the request, based on the acceptable types ordered by their quality values.

That is, `res.format()` will check the `Accept` HTTP request header, and invoke corresponding handler according the `Accept` value.

In your case, as the request is sent to `/index1.html`, the browser will automatically set `Accept` header as `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml...` -- `text/html` would be the first one. Then, when `res.format()` is executed, it will take `Accept` as `text/html` and return `hey, i am html`.

For `res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');`, please note you just set `Content-Type` header on response, it has nothing to do with `res.format()`.

Comment: Yes, as you said, i tried to transfer str data to server by Ajax, it works out to send "Hey, i am text", but when i transfer obj by Ajax, it still sent "Hey i am text", then i tried to use body-parser `router.use(bodyParser.json())` it still doesn't work to show "Hey, i am json". could you help check out again?

Comment: @SunnySun When you transfer obj by Ajax, what is the `Accept` request header?

Comment: @SunnySun I guess the `Accept` request header is `*/*` (automatically set by browser), then `res.format()` will always invoke the first handler and return "hey, i am text". In order to show "Hey, i am json", the `Accept` request header should be `application/json`

Comment: wow, it works as your instruction, when i set `xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');`, after `xhr.open('POST', 'index2.html', true);`  it shows "Hey, i am json"! vary appreciate your help!